# iP соединения с MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sql-server

Добрый день, не могу найти возможность получения IP сетевого адаптера клиента, с которого был отправлен запрос к MS SQL серверу, при условии того что у клиента несколько сетевых интерфейсов.
PS.
В sqlconnection statistics подобного нет, может на сервере есть нужная таблица.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На стороне сервера:

```
SELECT client_net_address
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
WHERE Session_id = @@SPID;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
--current session
SELECT  CONNECTIONPROPERTY('net_transport') AS [NET Transport],
        CONNECTIONPROPERTY('protocol_type') AS [Protocol Type],
        CONNECTIONPROPERTY('auth_scheme') AS [Auth Scheme],
        CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_net_address') AS [Local Net Address],
        CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_tcp_port') AS [Local TCP Port],
        CONNECTIONPROPERTY('client_net_address') AS [Client NET Address]


-all session
SELECT  * FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
```